# How to control gui text using the space bar in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

(Disclaimer: I am new to Unity so please bear with me)

Basically I want to have a text element that displays multiple sentences one letter at a time and will stop at the end of a sentence. Also, if the space bar is pressed then the remaining text from that sentence should display immediately, but if the sentence is already finished then the next sentence should show.

So far I have managed to get the text to display one letter at a time using strings stored in an array. However, I am now having difficulty navigating from index to index using the space bar and getting the complete sentence to show if the space bar is pressed.

The code is below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class TextScript : MonoBehaviour {

public Animator bar;
public float letterPause = 0.1f;
string[] strArray = new string[3];
string str;
int i;
int count;

void Start () {
    bar.enabled = true;

    strArray[0] = "Hello and welcome to the game";
    strArray[1] = "The is the next line of code";
    strArray[2] = "Testing the space bar";
    gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "";
    StartCoroutine(TypeText ());
}

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")) {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "";
        count = count + 1;
        i = i + 1;
        TypeText();
    }
}

IEnumerator TypeText () {
    for (i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++) {
        str = strArray[i];
        if (i == count) {
            foreach (char letter in str.ToCharArray()) {
                gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text += letter;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds (letterPause);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

So, I am not sure what is the best way to go about achieving what I really want. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have unity on this box to test this but try this

```
public float letterPause = 0.1f;
public float SentencePause = 2.0f;
string[] strArray = new string[3];
bool skipToNext = false;

void Start () {

    strArray[0] = "Hello and welcome to the game";
    strArray[1] = "The is the next line of code";
    strArray[2] = "Testing the space bar";
    gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "";
    StartCoroutine(TypeText ());
}

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")) {
        skipToNext = true;
    }
}

IEnumerator TypeText () {
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++) 
    {
        foreach (char letter in strArray[i].ToCharArray()) 
        {
            if (skipToNext)
            {
                gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = strArray[i];
                skipToNext = false;
                break;
            }

            gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text += letter;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (letterPause);
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (SentencePause);
        gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "";
    }

    gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = strArray[strArray.Length - 1];
}
```

Edited to reflect comment updates.

Comment: Thanks for the help, tried the code and it kind of worked. What I am having difficulty with is storing the script in the script and reading it to the gui text element rather than typing it in inspector.

Comment: What are you trying to set it to? In your current code you are setting the text to itself sort of.

Comment: I have now worked this part out, thanks for your help. If you look at the edited version of my question I have made some changes and have some other challenges.

Comment: You need a control of some sort. I updated my answer with a working example to do what you need to. In short I set a control `bool` that each letter iteration checks for and if its `true` it sets the full sentence and breaks the typing loop. You also needed a secondary wait time for how long you want the sentence to display before moving on.

Comment: Adding the bool worked great to get the sentence to complete when space is pressed. However, instead of using a secondary wait time I wanted to get the next sentence to display if space is pressed again.

Comment: change the second wait to a while loop that waits for the `bool` to toggle to true again before continuing. Keep in mind a while loop with no other break controls you run the risk of it never completing.

Comment: After some thought I think I'm going to leave it as is actually. Thank you so much for your help!